# 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int*'

Tags: arrays, c, function

When I try to run the following code, I get this error:

```
'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'
```

I'd like to return an array of casual numbers from 1 to 10 from the function but I can't figure out how to do it, can you help me?
The IDE underlines 'malloc'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int* casuali(int n);

int main()
{
    int n = 10;

    int* arrCasuali = casuali(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arrCasuali[i]);
    }
}

int* casuali(int n)
{
    int* arrCasuali = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arrCasuali[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    }

    return arrCasuali;
}
```

Comment: What compiler? Apart from `conio.h`, this code compiles fine for me under `clang`.

Comment: Tip: Seed *once* in your code. Don't seed per call.

Comment: I tried it on visual studio 2017 and Dev c++ but it doesn't work in both.

Comment: [You shouldn't need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Are you compiling in C++ mode inadvertently? Different rules apply there and the cast is necessary, but that is probably a mistake. Compile as C.

Comment: Your code is valid **C** and your question is tagged with **C** - but the error you mentioned will only be generated if you are compiling your code as **C++**. Check your compiler settings.

Comment: try adding `return 0;` at the end of your main function. You've told the compiler that it returns an int, but you're not returning anything.

Comment: The issue was I was compiling in c++ mode, the code works fine now, thanks a lot.

Comment: @bruceg: `main` is special and does not need an explicit `return` statement. If program control reaches the end of `main`, it will return success.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was just guessing that the OP was doing something weird with a C++ compiler that needed the return

Comment: do not compile as C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compiling the program as a C++ program.  To make the program to compile either compile it as a C program or at least change this declaration

```
int* arrCasuali = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

to the following

```
int* arrCasuali = ( int * )malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Pay attention to that among these headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
```

you need only three headers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

or if you are compiling the program as a C++ program then

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

and these two headers

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

are not standard C headers.

And you should free the allocated memory

```
free(  arrCasuali );
```

Comment: @Frax If your answer is answered then you can close it selecting the so-called best answer.